# React-Native android, reset default apps

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I my application I use react-native with rn-fetch-blob to fetch images/pdf files. On the first run, when I try to open, let's say, a pdf file, on android I get a native dialog, something like "Open with ..." and a list of apps that support pdf. I get to choose whether to use a certain app "just once" or "always".

If I select "always", I don't get the dialog anymore, which is expected. I am just wondering, is it possible to programmatically reset the selected default app, so I can get that dialog again?

Answer (score 1):

I think the other way to get desired behavior by using
[react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) 
also check the option: showAppsToView